# Client date and server date confusion

Tags: date, client-server, asp.net-2.0

I am working on a website in ASP.NET where e-mails can be scheduled for the future. But the problem is with the date difference between server and client.
As the server is in India, a USA user can schedule a date *after* today's date, as their time zone is different. Then this e-mail will never be sent, as the date has already been passed here.
Please suggest me how to deal with this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UTC time instead of local time.

Here's a link to an article in case you need more information:
https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215446/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081507-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I am going through the link. Hope this will help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

use UTC time and convert all times to it before you set the schedule.